# How to modify paging bar using MvcJqGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, pagination, fluent-interface, mvcjqgrid

I just started using the MvcJqGrid library, which is SO nice!

I have the following code:

```
@(Html.Grid("jqgUserGrid")
    .SetUrl(@Url.Action("GetUsers"))
    .SetRequestType(MvcJqGrid.Enums.RequestType.Post)
    .AddColumn(new Column("ID")
        .SetLabel("ID")
        .SetSearch(false))
    .AddColumn(new Column("UserLogin")
        .SetLabel("User Login")
        .SetSearch(true))
    .SetHeight(300)
    .SetPager("jqgUserPager")
)
```

This all works great, but I don't have any add/edit/delete buttons on my pager.

I've been searching for some documentation that shows how to add these, but haven't seen anything.

Do I have to add these the old fashioned jQuery way, or is there a fluent way to add these as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We did not include editing support in MvcJqGrid, I'm afraid you have to go the old fashioned jquery way.

Sorry I didn't notice your question earlier.

**EDIT**
Recently, basic support for inline editting was added: http://mvcjqgrid.skaele.it/Home/Edit